# Email being sent as HTML

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a php app that triggers an email.. Right now the recipient is getting the email with all of the HTML printed out in one blob of text.. Cant seem to find the error here, any ideas?

```
$user_info = get_userdata($venderid);

$shoperMail = $user_info->user_email;
$shoperName = $user_info->display_name;

$to      = $shoperMail.", info@orders.com";
$subject = "Sales Order from website";

$message  = '';
$message  = "Hi $shoperName,<br><br>";
$message .= "A Gift has been redeemed for your services.<br><br>";
$message .= "Customer: $currentuserName<br><br>";
$message .= "Redemption Amount: $$redempt<br><br>";
$message .= "Customer code:$confirmationCode<br><br>";
$message .= "To access their contact & order information, simply log in to your account & select: Gift Cards > Vendor Orders.<br><br>";
$message .= "*Once you have provided the customer with your company's voucher, certificate or online coupon code, please 'Approve' their purchase.<br><br>";
$message .= "Log in: <a href='".$url."/login/'>http://test.com</a><br><br>";
$message .= "If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me.<br><br>";
$message .= "Test test<br>order Gift Cards<br><i>doing cool stuff.</i><br><br>toll free: 866.test x.tes x 9<br><a href='http://www.test.com/'>Test.com</a>,<br><a href='http://www.facebook.com/test/'>facebook.com/test</a><br><a href='http://twitter.com/test/'>twitter.com/test</a><br><br><br>" ;
$message .= "**The information transmitted is intended only for the person or entity to which it is addressed and may contain confidential and/or privileged material. Any review, re-transmission, dissemination or other use of, or taking of any action in reliance upon this information by persons or entities other than the intended recipient is prohibited. If you received this email in error, please contact the sender immediately by return electronic transmission and then immediately delete this transmission, including all attachments, without copying, distributing or disclosing same. ";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "To: ".$shoperMail."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: orders@prders.com\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: use \n instead of <br/>,<br> in your massage body text

Comment: don't build mime emails by hand. use phpmailer or swiftmailer. they automate it all for you, and all you have to do is provide the html. you're also not providing a full valid html document. just some text with html tags in it.

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam - it's supposed to be a HTML email. If you use \n, it won't appear in the finished HTML.

Comment: @andrewsi  I cant redo this with phpmailer at the moment unfortunately..  If \n wont work is there anything else I can do? This should work one way or another

Comment: @js111 - Does it come through as a HTML email when you mail yourself?

Comment: @js111 - it might be worth giving @diggy's answer a try, too - if you're using Wordpress, you can try `wp_mail`

Comment: Wait, /n doesn't work? I'm using PHPMailer 5.2.3 and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the HTML content type, example from the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail):

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'my_set_html_content_type' );
wp_mail( 'me@example.net', 'The subject', '<p>The <em>HTML</em> message</p>' );
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'my_set_html_content_type' ); // reset content-type
```

Filter callback:

```
function my_set_html_content_type()
{
    return 'text/html';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've embedded your code in the same html-mail-markup that I usually use.

Give this a try:

```
// Getting info    
$user_info = get_userdata($venderid);
$shoperMail = $user_info->user_email;
$shoperName = $user_info->display_name;
$to = $shoperMail.", info@orders.com";

// HTML
$message  = '';
$message  = "Hi $shoperName,<br><br>";
$message .= "A Gift has been redeemed for your services.<br><br>";
$message .= "Customer: $currentuserName<br><br>";
$message .= "Redemption Amount: $$redempt<br><br>";
$message .= "Customer code:$confirmationCode<br><br>";
$message .= "To access their contact & order information, simply log in to your account & select: Gift Cards > Vendor Orders.<br><br>";
$message .= "*Once you have provided the customer with your company's voucher, certificate or online coupon code, please 'Approve' their purchase.<br><br>";
$message .= "Log in: <a href='".$url."/login/'>http://test.com</a><br><br>";
$message .= "If you have any questions, please don't hesitate to contact me.<br><br>";
$message .= "Test test<br>order Gift Cards<br><i>doing cool stuff.</i><br><br>toll free: 866.test x.tes x 9<br><a href='http://www.test.com/'>Test.com</a>,<br><a href='http://www.facebook.com/test/'>facebook.com/test</a><br><a href='http://twitter.com/test/'>twitter.com/test</a><br><br><br>" ;
$message .= "**The information transmitted is intended only for the person or entity to which it is addressed and may contain confidential and/or privileged material. Any review, re-transmission, dissemination or other use of, or taking of any action in reliance upon this information by persons or entities other than the intended recipient is prohibited. If you received this email in error, please contact the sender immediately by return electronic transmission and then immediately delete this transmission, including all attachments, without copying, distributing or disclosing same. ";

// Subject
$subject = "Sales Order from website";

// Header 
$innerboundary ="=_".time()."_=";
$header ="MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$header.="To: ".$to."\n"; 
$header.="From: orders@prders.com\n";
$header.="Reply-To: orders@prders.com\n";
$header.="X-Mailer: kmPHP-Mailer\n"; 
$header.="Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n\tboundary=\"".$innerboundary."\"\n";

// Body
$body.="\n--".$innerboundary."\n"; 
$body.="Content-Type: text/html;\n\tcharset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n"; 
$body.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n"; 
$body.=chunk_split(base64_encode(($message)))."\n\n"; 
$body.="\n--".$innerboundary."--\n"; 
$body.="\n\n"; 

// Send
mail($shoperMail,$subject,$body,$header);
```

Answer (score 0):

To reiterate Marc B comment above

> don't build mime emails by hand. use [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). they automate it all for you, and all you have to do is provide the html.

Doing this will make it much easier for you to solve your problem by doing it in a differnt way.